# How do I loop or apply an ifelse statement with 2 conditions over many columns?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, apply

I constantly need to create new columns in r based on conditions of other columns. Because I work with time series data the columns the conditions are based on change for each time point. How do I loop an ifelse statement to create new variables when the ifelse statement is also changing for each new time point.

I usually just copy paste my ifelse statement but there is so much room for error. I would rather just use a loop or apply statement. For context for the code below we collect sputum at 13 different time points. We want to create 13 variables for those time points representing positive sputum. Sputum is considered "positive" based on the 2 conditions in the ifelse statement.

```
data$smear_bl <- ifelse(data$s_concafb_sputum_specimen_1== 0 | data$s_concafb_sputum_specimen_1==5, 0, 1)

data$smear_2 <- ifelse(data$s_concafb_sputum_specimen_2 == 0 | data$s_concafb_sputum_specimen_2 == 5, 0, 1 )

data$smear_3 <- ifelse(data$s_concafb_sputum_specimen_3 == 0 | data$s_concafb_sputum_specimen_3 == 5, 0, 1 )

data$smear_4 <- ifelse(data$s_concafb_sputum_specimen_4 == 0 | data$s_concafb_sputum_specimen_4 == 5, 0, 1 )

....

data$smear_mo5 <- ifelse(data$s_concafb_sputum_specimen_13 == 0 | data$s_concafb_sputum_specimen_13 == 5, 0, 1 )
```

I am hoping for 13 new variables as the above coding provides but through the use of a simpler statement! Then I would like to be able to sum those columns (they consist of 1's and 0s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an index to differentiate column names, you could do something like:

```
for (i in 1:13) { # use however many columns or variables you want
    colname <- paste0('s_concafb_sputum_specimen_', i)
    varname <- paste0('smear_', i)
    data[,varname] <- !(data[, colname] == 0 | data[, colname] == 5) # this maps to a boolean but TRUE or FALSE evaluate to 1 and 0 respectively
}
```

Comment: Wow it worked! Thank you so much, the data was not intentionally indexed but luckily turned out to be!

Comment: Glad to help :) feel free to checkmark this as the answer if it helped!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common use case where your data was recorded in "wide" format, but best analyzed in "long" format. That means that where you currently have a separate column the same type of measurement at each time step, you want two columns: *time* = the time step, and *value* = the measurement at that time step.

The concept, as Hadley Wickam writes, is that you want to work with tidy data in which:

1. Each variable is a column.
2. Each observation is a row
3. Each value is a cell.

Here's how to tidy your data with tidyr. Note: if your data doesn't look like what I've made up, then give us a minimal working example of your data and I'll update this solution. The gather function takes a little getting used to, but is super useful once you get there.

```
library(tidyr) # for gather function

# Making up some data
wide.df <- data.frame(s_concafb_sputum_specimen_1 = 1,
                      s_concafb_sputum_specimen_2 = 0,
                      s_concafb_sputum_specimen_3 = 5,
                      s_concafb_sputum_specimen_4 = 2,
                      s_concafb_sputum_specimen_5 = 1)

# Converting from wide to long
long.df <- gather(wide.df, key = "time", value = "value")

# New column from condition
long.df$smear <- ifelse(long.df$value == 0 | long.df$value == 5, 0, 1)

# Result
long.df

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   time                        value smear
#   <chr>                       <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_1     1     1
# 2 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_2     0     0
# 3 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_3     5     0
# 4 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_4     2     1
# 5 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_5     1     1
```

You've also asked how to sum the values in *smear* for your sputum specimens while the data is in long form. I would use the `summarize` function in the library `dplyr`. As my original sample data for this solution only has a single value for each specimen, we'll just duplicate each row in the data frame so we have multiple values for each specimen to sum. Also, the *time* column identifying the specimen should really be a factor-type, so we'll change that to ease future analysis.

```
doubled.df <- bind_rows(long.df, long.df)
doubled.df$time <- as.factor(doubled.df$time)

library(dplyr)

# If you're not familiar with the pipe operator (%>%) provided by dplyr, it just takes
# the output of the thing to its left and makes it the first argument to the function
# to its right. I think it makes code more readable than nesting a bunch of functions,
# and more compact than saving stuff in a bunch of intermediate variables, which are 
# two other ways to accomplish the same thing.
doubled.df %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  summarize(Sum = sum(smear))

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   time                          Sum
#   <fct>                       <dbl>
# 1 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_1     2
# 2 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_2     0
# 3 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_3     0
# 4 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_4     2
# 5 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_5     2

# Alternatively
summarize(group_by(doubled.df, time), Sum = sum(smear))

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   time                          Sum
#   <fct>                       <dbl>
# 1 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_1     2
# 2 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_2     0
# 3 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_3     0
# 4 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_4     2
# 5 s_concafb_sputum_specimen_5     2
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. So say I wanted to sum the smear results for all s_concafb_sputum_specimen_1 for example, I know how to do that if i convert it back to wide, but is there a way to do it in long format as well?

Comment: I would do that in long format using the library dplyr, which along with tidyr is what I use most for wrangling data. Please edit your question to add this and I'll add code for the solution to my answer.

Comment: I just noticed a problem with the code in my answer that should prevent it from running. I'm going to fix that!

Comment: Great added to the question that I need the sum!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` in base R to create new columns. Also we can skip `ifelse` and wrap `as.integer` on logical values to get 1/0.

```
#Columns to test
cols <- c("a", "b")
df[paste0("new_", cols)] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) as.integer(x %in% c(0, 5)))

df
#  a b new_a new_b
#1 2 0     0     1
#2 3 1     0     0
#3 0 2     1     0
#4 5 3     1     0
#5 4 4     0     0
#6 1 5     0     1
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1), b = 0:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more base approach:

```
cols <- names(DF)[-1]
new_cols <- paste('new', cols, sep = '_')

DF[, new_cols] <- !(DF[cols] == 0 | DF[cols] == 5)


  grp a b new_a new_b
1   1 2 0  TRUE FALSE
2   1 3 1  TRUE  TRUE
3   2 0 2 FALSE  TRUE
4   2 1 3  TRUE  TRUE
5   3 2 3  TRUE  TRUE
6   3 3 2  TRUE  TRUE
7   4 0 1 FALSE  TRUE
8   4 1 0  TRUE FALSE
```

The `+` coerces the boolean into a numeric and the `!` negates the logical comparison.

If then you want to sum everything, it would be easy to add `colSums` to the original logical statement:

```
colSums(DF[new_cols])

# new_a new_b 
#   6     6

colSums(!(DF[cols] == 0 | DF[cols] == 5))

# a b 
# 6 6
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(grp = rep(1:4, each = 2),
                 a = c(2, 3, 0, 1, sample(4)-1),
                 b = c(0:3, 3:0))
```